# Intercept HTTP POST response from Reverse Proxy in Apache

Tags: reverse-proxy, mod-rewrite, apache2, httpd, web

I have following configuration in my Apache server and requirement is to intercept HTTP POST request to /api/submit endpoint and trigger a CURL request to a remote URL before forwarding it to backend server (http://localhost:1212).

```
ProxyPass /api/ http://localhost:1212/api
ProxyPassReverse /api/ http://localhost:1212/api
```

I looked for various documentations online related to mod_lua etc but without luck.
Can this be acheived using apache httpd server ?.

Comment: I believe you would be better of adding this functionality in your api application instead.

Comment: Why do you want your Apache server to do this?

Comment: It's just some POC i am trying to do. Appreciate if you could share few solutions using Apache.

Comment: you want to make a POST request, which is supposed to be volatile and discarted right after use and not proxy but to trigger a curl request elsewhere. What are you after exactly? It seems to be nothing good.